# Why does VS Debug build allocates variables so far apart?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, visual-c++, allocation

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and I noticed that in debug builds, the variables are allocated so far apart from one another. I looked at *Project Properties* and tried searching online but could not find anything. I ran the following code below in both Debug and Release mode and here are the respective outputs.

```
int main() {
        int a = 3;
        int b = 5;
        int c = 8;
        int d[5] = { 10,10,10,10,10 };
        int e = 14;

        std::cout << "a: " << &a 
                << "\nb: " << &b
                << "\nc: " << &c 
                << "\nd_start: " << &d[0]
                << "\nd_end: "   << &d[4] + 1
                << "\ne: " << &e 
            << std::endl;
}
```

As you can see below, variables are allocated as you would expect (one after the other) with no wasted memory in between. Even the last variable, `e`, is optimized to slot between c and d.

```
// Release_x64 Build Ouput
a:          0000003893EFFC40
b:          0000003893EFFC44
c:          0000003893EFFC48
d_start:    0000003893EFFC50
d_end:      0000003893EFFC64
e:          0000003893EFFC4C    // e is optimized in between c and d
```

Below is the output that confuses me. Here you can see that `a` and `b` are allocated 32 bytes apart! So there is 28 bytes of wasted/uninitialized memory between them. The same thing happens for other variables except for the `int d[5]`. `d` has 32 uninitialized bytes after `c` but only has 24 uninitialized bytes before `e`.

```
// Debug_x64 Build Output
a:          00000086D7EFF3F4
b:          00000086D7EFF414
c:          00000086D7EFF434
d_start:    00000086D7EFF458
d_end:      00000086D7EFF46C
e:          00000086D7EFF484
```

My question is that why is this happening? Why does the MSVC allocate these variables so far apart from one another and what determines how much space to separate them by so that it's different for arrays?

Comment: Most likely this is so it can catch buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug version of the allocates storage differently than the release version. In particular, the debug version allocates some space at the beginning and end of each block of storage, so its allocation patterns are somewhat different.

The debug allocator also checks the storage at the start and end of the block it allocated to see if it has been damaged in any way.

Storage is allocated in quantized chunks, where the quantum is unspecified but is something like 16, or 32 bytes. Thus, if you allocated a DWORD array of six elements (size = 6 * sizeof(DWORD) bytes = 24 bytes) then the allocator will actually deliver 32 bytes (one 32-byte quantum or two 16-byte quanta). So if you write element [6] (the seventh element) you overwrite some of the "dead space" and the error is not detected. But in the release version, the quantum might be 8 bytes, and three 8-byte quanta would be allocated, and writing the [6] element of the array would overwrite a part of the storage allocator data structure that belongs to the next chunk. After that it is all downhill. There error might not even show up until the program exits! You can construct similar "boundary condition" situations for any size quantum. Because the quantum size is the same for both versions of the allocator, but the debug version of the allocator adds hidden space for its own purposes, you will get different storage allocation patterns in debug and release mode.